# How to add a remove/clear field icon to an input field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

A standard input field with `type="date"` in AngularJS 1.3 provides a "Clear field" icon. [Here is](http://grab.by/Cet0) what I mean.

Is there a way to add such "Clear field" icon to an input field with `type="text"`?

Comment: A plain JS, HTML, CSS version ====> http://jsbin.com/bebug/5/edit?output

Answer (score 4):

This isn't an Angular thing.  It's a HTML 5 feature.  You can simulate the same clear x button by using `type='search'`.  Your input will still look like a text input.

```
<input type="search">
```

Answer (score 0):

both solutions do the job. The difference is in styles.

1. With the `<input type="search">` the input fields gets [rounded corners](http://grab.by/CeKA) by default (which gives it an intuitive-level feeling of a search box :) and the initial [placeholder text](http://grab.by/CeKq).
   I believe I read somewhere that it is not recommended to manipulate shadow DOM, so I assumed it is better to not fiddle with it. Correct me if I am wrong. PS: It is great to find out about the standard input `type="search"`.
2. A `plain JS, HTML, CSS` [solution](http://jsbin.com/bebug/5/edit?output) proposed in the comments to my question [does exactly](http://grab.by/CeKO) what I was looking for. I still used `type="text"` for the input box, with a `class="clearable"`.

Where `class="clearable"` is as follows:

```
.clearable{
 background: #fff
 url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBwAHAIAAAP///5KSkiH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAHAAcAAAIMTICmsGrIXnLxuDMLADs=) no-repeat right -10px center;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 padding: 3px 18px 3px 4px; /* Use the same right padding (18) in jQ! */
 border-radius: 3px;
 transition: background 0.4s;
}
.clearable.x  { background-position: right 5px center; }
.clearable.onX{ cursor: pointer; }
```

It is up to the use-case and personal preferences. Both solutions are great.

@God is good, would you be so kind to rewrite your comment as an answer, s.t. I can accept it.

@Lloyd Banks, thank you very much for your solution as well, which would be great for a search type of input field.

### Note

If one uses other classes besides `clearable`, keep in mind that there can be conflicts.